# Is SIFT a segmentation algorithm?

Tags: computer-vision, sift

I must track a person in a scene using a segmentation algorithm.   [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) will do the job but is it definitely considered a segmentation algorithm or something else altogether?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SIFT is not a segmentation algorithm. SIFT can be considered and image description method, a keypoint matching algorithm an object recognition method but definitely not a segmentation algorithm.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case so I avoided SIFT.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

SIFT locates interest points, ie points that have a well defined location in the image. This will often be corners and line ends.